# PHP in Jade templates

Tags: php, jade

По работе достался старый сайт и я задумал перейти на Jade с обычного php шаблонизатора, никак не могу догадаться, как переделать такой код на jade( думал использовать jade-php)?

```
<div class="item<?= ($i > 8) ? ' hidden' : '' ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
| <div class="item<?= ($i > 8) ? ' hidden' : '' ?>">
```